# How do I manually deploy a specific TFS changeset using TeamCity?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have the following setup in TeamCity:

A) CI upon check-in with build, tests and deploy to test environment.
B) Manual deploy

Deployment is based on MSBuild build task with MsDeployServiceUrl parameters.
My CVS is TFS and im not using any build scripts.

A is working great, what I can't figure out is B.
Now, what I would like B to do is, when triggered (manually), get the source from TFS as a changeset based on the latest pinned build of A, build the source (Using build step MSBuild with /p:Configuration=Release) and run the deploy to a production server.

My question here is, how do I get source from a specific changeset from TFS based on the build id of last pinned build of A? Is that even possible?

I have read the documentation on custom builds and artifacts:  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Triggering+a+Custom+Build
But could not figure out how to use it in my scenario and I am not even sure if this is the road to take on specific need.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

You need to set "Artifacts path" in build configuration A to something like:

```
/**/* => Src
```

And then in build configuration B set "Artifact Dependencies" to something this:

```
"Artifacts path" = Src/**/*
"Destination path" = Builds/Release
```

And finally use this "Destination path" as a prefix when adding the "Build file path" in the MSBuild "Build step" on B.

Works like a charm every build! :-)